# Error while running bazel build tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:155:1: no such package '@llvm//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build the tensorflow from source 
- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

I installed bazel following this link https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html.

I had done all the setups as per the link mentioned above
while executing the following command

> bazel build --config=opt
>   //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

I am getting this error

> tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:155:1: no such package '@llvm//':
>   java.io.IOException: Error downloading
>   [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/archive/6e11f192fc555ebfca595403b0f5cdc3aa47a4de.tar.gz,
>   https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/archive/6e11f192fc555ebfca595403b0f5cdc3aa47a4de.tar.gz]
>   ... Read timed out and referenced by
>   '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:licenses'

I am kind of blocked here, any help is appreciated